# How to merge multiple draft-js ContentState's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have a collection of multiple `draft-js` `ContentStates` which i want to merge together to display them in one `<Editor />`

**Why?**
Through my GUI you can edit text snippets individually and then at a later point join them together.
You are then presented with the resulting text, which you again can still edit.

I persist the individual `ContentStates` as follows:

```
const contentState = EditorState.getCurrentContent();
const raw = convertToRaw(contentState);
```

Which gives me an object like:

```
{
   blocks: [...],
   entityMap: {...}
}
```

What i tried, was manually merging the `blocks` and `entityMap`, to get a resulting raw contentState, which i could then parse with `convertFromRaw`

However, each block has a supposedly unique key, where on different contentStates these keys overlap and are not unique.

So the result in that case is that some blocks are being overridden by others with the same key.

Does anyone have an idea for an easier way to achieve what im doing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in draft.js to generate unique keys:

```
import { genKey } from 'draft-js'
```

If you look at its code, you'll see that it's stateful (see that `seenKeys`?):

```
const seenKeys = {};
const MULTIPLIER = Math.pow(2, 24);
  
function generateRandomKey(): string {
    let key;
  
    while (key === undefined || seenKeys.hasOwnProperty(key) || !isNaN(+key)) 
    {
       key = Math.floor(Math.random() * MULTIPLIER).toString(32);
    }
  
    seenKeys[key] = true;
    return key;
}
  
module.exports = generateRandomKey;
```

So I believe, you can solve your problem by mapping over blocks and regenerating their keys (I'll use Ramda for more concise and expressive code):

```
import * as R from 'ramda'

const mergedObjectWithOverlappingKeys = {
   blocks: [...],
   entityMap: {...}
}

const result = R.evolve({
   blocks: R.map(R.assoc('key', genKey())),
})(mergedObjectWithOverlappingKeys)
```